# installing packages over pythonbrew

Tags: python, package

I installed python 2.7 with python brew. How do I install packages to work with it? I installed MySQLdb with synaptic, but I am unable to import it in python 2.7.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Answer (score 6):

Switch to 2.7:

```
pythonbrew switch 2.7
```

Curl and run get-pip to get the correct version of pip for 2.7:

```
curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

This will install the version of pip for 2.7. Check it by doing:

```
pip --version
```

Turn off pythonbrew:

```
pythonbrew off
```

Check the version of pip again, and it should be using the one for your default Python:

```
pip --version
```

If all is good, then switch back to 2.7 in pythonbrew and install mysql-python for 2.7:

```
pythonbrew switch 2.7
pip install mysql-python
```

Check to see that it is installed for 2.7:

```
pip freeze
```

Pip freeze will give you a listing of all installed libraries for the current active version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install pip, which is a recursive acronym: Pip Installs Packages. This thread talks about installing it on [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows), on Ubuntu I did `sudo apt get install pip.`

Ok, your problem is that "mysqldb" is not a python package. You need to use MySQLdb as a backend, or simply install sqlite3 and import *that* into Python, which is a module that mimics SQL. If you end up using an actual full-on database, like `MySQLdb` or `PostgreSQL`, you'll probably need to install `SQLAlchemy`, which is a  Python module to interface with those.

Comment: By the way Pip is python specific.

Comment: I did install pip. But 'pip install MySQLdb' is not working :(

Comment: Do other packages install correctly? Try BeautifulSoup or something if you don't have that already, which should be available through pip.

Comment: BeautifulSoup did get installed. But I still cannot import it in 2.7. It installs to default python dist that comes with ubuntu (2.65) .

Comment: Regarding mysqldb not being a python package, I am not sure. I can install it using synaptic and I can import it in python 2.65 (default python)

Comment: Hmmm. Ok, forget the Soup, see my above modifications and try installing sqllite3, if you're ok with testing that. As far as I experienced they're very similar on the front-end, so it's definitely fine for troubleshooting and just getting started.

Comment: Ok, try using `switch <version>` and then installing it, if you haven't already. Otherwise you're just installing it to your original version, Python 2.65, as pip is assigning it to your active version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a version of pip for each Python version. Do you have easy install available? If so you can do

```
easy_install-2.7 pip
```

Is there a specific reason that you are installing Python via home brew though? You do know that Ubuntu has as a package.

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

Will give you a version of Python that is already nicely set up.

I also believe that you should be trying to install the Python package called mysql-python.

```
pip install mysql-python
```

MySQLDB is not a Python package. It's the actual database.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @leta-rogers. However, I didn't have to install pip separately. Installing python using pythonbrew installed pip (for python 2.7) for me as well:

```
pythonbrew install 2.7
pythonbrew switch 2.7
pip install mysql-python
```